# apache airflow execution date has microseconds

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have been deploying my DAGs with the default settings, but sometimes the DAG gets out of sync and starts running with a weird execution date such as
`11-21T11:12:33.877171` but all but other runs have the execution date with the format `MM-DDT00:00:00`

I have not set the schedule interval so it uses the default:

`schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(1)`

I also always set my start date to be a datetime such as:

`'start_date': datetime(2017, 9, 6)`

Once the first run happens with the new weird execution date then all the subsequent runs run one schedule interval after that execution date instead of at midnight like I would like.

Also, sometimes this issue also happens when I deploy a new DAG and the first execution date is not `MM-DDT00:00:00`

I have two questions:

1. If the execution date gets messed up how do I fix it so that it goes back to the normal schedule of starting right after midnight ?
2. When I deploy a new DAG how can I ensure that it starts right after midnight ?

Comment: `time.clock()` returned float time.